# ERROR: Could not build wheels for polars, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-polars

When I install polars in the new environment:

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for polars
Failed to build polars
ERROR: Could not build wheels for polars, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Polars = = 0.14.7 has been installed normally

Comment: This can occur when you have a pip version that does not support our binary wheels. An update of pip to the latest version often fixes this issue.